# Computer lagging when writting in section or subsection

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I'm writting a long document. Each time, in a LaTeX document, I had a new section, subsection or subsubsection, the computer is lagging for each modification I do. It could be just adding a section or modifying the name of it.

This is occuring with Texmaker.

Is this something normal ? Why ? And if it's not, how to fix it ?

Comment: What do you mean by `lagging`? The missing entry in the ToC the first time you compile after adding a new `\section` etc? Yes, that's normal and there's nothing to fix then.

Comment: tex is not involved while you are writing (unless you have some automatic preview loop set up, which is not common) so any issues are just issues with your editor (but you have not said what editor you are using)

Comment: Does the editor (continually) parse the file? Does it only happen when you are 'partway' through writing the `\section`? That is, does lag when you have an unmatched brace -- `\section{This Is My Long Section That Is Not Yet Close`?

Comment: You're all right, It should come from the editor (Texmaker). I edit my post.

And, by lagging, I mean the computer almost freeze for the so much ressource it ask to do this.

It lagg the same if it's close or not, if I'm just adding a caracter or adding 200 to the name. So now, I write everything outside the name of section and copy paste it to have my computer lagging less time but I find this strange...

Comment: @zeslayer: Try with another TeX editor or a general editor and compile manually instead

Comment: How large is your document? If an outline of your source code is created while you type and you have a large document, this may result in this behavior.

Comment: ChristianHupfer, I have no problem for compiling. The problem is only when I add/modify a section in Texmaker


@epR8GaYuh, The output is something like 40 pages. It's not so big. How could I know if something is created when tipping ? Is this common in Texmaker ? I thought everything was created by compiling.

Comment: 40 pages of output could already be a problem if an outline is created as you type if there are lots of things to parse. I do not use Texmaker by myself, but having a look at the screenshots there is an overview of the current document in the left column of the screen. Updating this could end up in this behavior.